# PHP DateTime Format Change

Tags: php

Here is my code and I do not know why the two DateTime values are quite different.

```
<?php
    $Record['DateTime']='31-May-2018 19-15-28';
    $DateTime = date('d-M-Y H-i-s', strtotime($Record['DateTime']));
    $Record['Send_Time'] = date('d-M-Y H:i:s', strtotime($DateTime));
    print_r($Record);
```

And here is my result-

```
Array
(
    [DateTime] => 31-May-2018 19-15-28
    [Send_Time] => 01-Jan-1970 01:00:00
)
```

Comment: `31-May-2018 19-15-28` is not a valid datetime string

Comment: can I not put - instead of : for H:i:s arrangement?

Comment: You either have to use a valid datetime format or use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` if you insist on using a custom format. But you can't make your own format up and expect PHP to be able to do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to use DateTime object. Thanks again.